# c# define treeview property programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm new to C# and ASP.net. In my project, I'm showing a list of nodes in a treeview control. In my front end, I can create a treeview and define its populate method like

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tv1" runat ="server" ExpandDepth ="2" PopulateNodesFromClient="false" OnTreeNodePopulate="TreeNodePopulate"/>
```

What is the equivalent way of defining it programmatically?

```
tv1.OnTreeNodePopulate = "TreeNodePopulate"; // isn't working
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook the TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate to your TreeView control. You can do that declaratively from the markup...

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" OnTreeNodePopulate="TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate">
```

or, imperatively from code behind...

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    TreeView1.TreeNodePopulate += TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the `TreeNodePopulate` event not set the `string`, check code below:

```
tv1.TreeNodePopulate += TreeView_TreeNodePopulate;
```

and the subscriber method:

```
void TreeView_TreeNodePopulate(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your code here
}
```